# Excel April 2021 Patch - Broken Add-In

Tags: excel, office365, add-in, patch

Has anyone experience issues with COM Automation Add-Ins in Excel 2013, 2016, 2019 after the Office patch from April 2021?

We have an Add-In that contains UDF installed worldwide that stopped working after the patch and there is no way to find a fix for it without uninstalling Excel and reverting it to a version before the patch.

Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: Was the patch tested before people told to install it? We used to run 2 behind the latest to avoid any issues from latest patches not working - let others test was a good motto :)

Comment: Are there any old XLM macro functions involved?